# How can I get a component of a rigidbodies velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to detect the y velocity in my rigidbody in order to determine whether the player can jump or not. For some reason the component I get from rb.velocity[2] does not match what I see when I log rb.velocity in console. Some help understanding how to get that vertical velocity component from the rigidbody would be very helpful.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector3 xvector = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
    public Vector3 yvector = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
    public float strafeforce = 1f ;
    public float jumpforce = 15f;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("right") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(strafeforce, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse) ; 
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("left") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(-strafeforce, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse) ; 
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("up") )
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (rb.velocity[2] == 0)
            {
                rb.AddForce(0, jumpforce, 0, ForceMode.Impulse) ;
            }
            Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
            Debug.Log(rb.velocity[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the second value from rb.velocity doesn't match the value I get from rb.velocity[2] for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried using `rb.velocity.x`, `rb.velocity.y`, and `rb.velocity.z` instead? I believe that's the recommended way to get the velocity components of a Rigidbody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# indexes start from 0. That means that index 2 would actually be the 3rd component of the vector (i.e. the z velocity). If you want the second component you should actually use `rb.velocity[1]`.

However if you want to get a specific component, for example the y velocity, you can instead use `rb.velocity.x`, `rb.velocity.y` and `rb.velocity.z`. This makes the code easier to read, as you can see at a glance which axis you are trying to access.

Comment: This worked well, had to end up rounding it off because it was displaying some tiny fraction of a vertical velocity but otherwise worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference only exists in the Log due to different `ToString` implementations.

Unity's default formatting for [`Vector3.ToString`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L463) uses `F1` which rounds all values to a single decimal

> ```
>    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
>    {
>        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
>            format = "F1";
>        return UnityString.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})", x.ToString(format, formatProvider), y.ToString(format, formatProvider), z.ToString(format, formatProvider));
>    }
> ```

This is not the case for the default `float.ToString`.

Id you want to be sure they match in the log use e.g.

```
Debug.Log(rb.velocity.ToString("G9"));
Debug.Log(rb.velocity[2].ToString("G9"));
```

or actually simply

```
Debug.Log(rb.velocity.z.ToString("G9"));
```